# kofax import connector does not collect system copied files

Tags: kofax

I have 2 `KTA process`, the first collects email attachments and then uses a `.net` activity to flatten with a `cmd utility`.

It is called as a `.vbs` script from the KTA `.net` activity.

The file is output to new directory. The second process is supposed to pick up again via file import connector but wont detect the file.

If I copy it there manually it collects.

Any other method like windows scheduler copy or VB copy or KTA process copy causes the import connector not to pick up the file.

I tried trigger and time based modified file.

Any suggestions what could be the problem?

Thanks

Shane

Comment: What version of KTA are you using (Major.Minor.ServicePack.FixPack)?  Once you have system copied files in the folder not being picked up, if you modify/rename one of them, does it get imported?

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for replying. I'm using version 7.4.1.0.0.1010. and the answer is no. If I change file name it does nothing. I need to cut/copy the file elsewhere and then copy it back before it gets picked up.

Comment: You might check to see if there are any unusual permissions differences on the files when they are not being picked up (compared to when they work), but other than that you should probably open a tech support case for this one (with Kofax or with the Kofax partner that supports you as applicable).

Comment: Thanks, Stephen I have opened a case with Kofax, it is just urgent to get a resolution so I thought I would reach out to others as well. As for the permissions, it is something I already checked and the user I do the copy with is the same user that the service runs under and is the file owner when I view it.   The user has local admin rights and log on as a service right.

Comment: That makes sense.  This issue sounds like something that the support team will need to dig into and diagnose, so I don't have any answer I can suggest here.  Good luck!